# Can the Hanning Window be represented in the time domain

Tags: fourier-transform, window-functions

I know the Hanning window, $w_{Hann}(n) = 1 - \cos \left(2\pi \frac{n}{N} \right)$, is typically applied to discrete Fourier transforms. $N$ being the total number of points in a transient signal that is to be transformed with the DFT. However, I'm trying to have a look at how this window (which is what I use to measure) affects the spectral line shape of the resultant Fourier transform.

For now I simply say my transient signal is a damped oscillator of the form 
$$f(t) = e^{-t/\tau} \cos(\omega_0 t).$$The Fourier transorm of which is well known to be a Lorentzian profile. However As I measure my data with a Hanning window I want to take the Fourier transform of
$$f(t) w_{Hann}(t)$$
This means I need the Hanning window in the time domain, which I assume to be simply
$$w_{Hann}(t) = 1 - \cos \left(2\pi \frac{t}{T} \right)$$ where $T$ is the averaging time for my Fourier transform.

Is this a good approach and a sounds assumption I can make with the Hanning window in a time domain rather than for a discrete index of points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you mean is that you want the continuous-time Hann window instead of the discrete-time window?

$$w_{Hann}(t) = 1 - \cos \left(2\pi \frac{t}{T} \right)$$

is not correct, [since it goes to 0 at 0](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-cos(2*pi*t)+from+-0.5+to+0.5).

Blackman & Tukey give the continuous time window as:

$$D_2(\tau)=\frac 1 2 \left (1+\cos \frac{\pi \tau}{T_m} \right )$$

for $|\tau| < T_m$ and 0 elsewhere.

[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F2*%281%2Bcos%28pi*tau%2F5%29%29+from+-5+to+5)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hann_function

https://archive.org/details/TheMeasurementOfPowerSpectra/page/n58

Comment: Exactly! This was my concern, could you tell me what $\tau$ and $T_m$ are? Thanks

Comment: Also if you have a source for this, that would be really helpful

Comment: @QuantumPenguin $\tau$ is the argument of the function (so time if you're working in the time domain).  $T_m$ is the window length

Comment: One final question, when you say window length, in the context of time rather than a discrete, you mean the time that the FFT would be averaged for in seconds?

Comment: @QuantumPenguin Well it's a window, so it's essentially a weighted moving average. The window function is 0 outside of its width, so picks up nothing of the original signal outside that region

Comment: @QuantumPenguin The wider your window, the Fourier transform becomes higher resolution in frequency, but lower resolution in time

Comment: I understand this, but usually it's applied to a DFT right? So it would be the length of points in the sample that will be DFT'd. But now we are in the non-discrete time domain, so I figure the corresponding must be the amount of time that the transient is acquired for. Fundamentally, how do you define $T_m$ or the window length in the continuous time window?

Comment: @QuantumPenguin Windows can be applied in continuous-time or discrete-time, yes.  "how do you define $T_m$ or the window length in the continuous time window?"  It's the length of the window (actually half the length, with this definition).  If $T_m$ is 5, then the window is 10 long.

Comment: Thanks for your time and answering my questions!